# Python Zabbix API trigger get with array

Tags: python, arrays, api, python-3.x, zabbix

According to [Zabbix API documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/api/reference_commentary#common_get_method_parameters) the parameter 'search' "Accepts an array, where the keys are property names, and the values are strings to search for. "

So what I'm trying to do in the code below is search for text fields that contain the word "Access" or "XSD".

```
for h in HostID:
    gatilho = zapi.trigger.get(
        host='apacheserver01',
        expandDescription = 'true',
        output='extend',
        search={'description':['Access','XSD']},
)
```

Somebody can help me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Zabbix API the parameter `search={'description':['Access','XSD']},` will search for 'Access' and 'XSD' in the same description field.

So the result will be: description: 'Access to XSD failed'

But what I want is a "OR":

description: 'Access to XSD failed'

description: 'XSD log ERROR'

description: 'Acces to system XPTO failed'

To do that another parameter is needed: **`searchByAny='true'`**, this tell to search for any word in search parameter.

```
for h in HostID:
    gatilho = zapi.trigger.get(
        host='apacheserver01',
        expandDescription = 'true',
        output='extend',
        searchByAny='true'
        search={'description':['Access','XSD']},
)
```